# Android httpClient

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I am hitesh my problem is ,i work on httpclient in andriod i gave internet permission to my application and i run my application and click on button the tehy gave unfortunately stopped. please help me there my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final   EditText user=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    final   EditText pass=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    Button login=(Button) findViewhere`ById(R.id.login);
    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String u=user.getText().toString();
            String p=pass.getText().toString();
            HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost("http://202.164.53.122");
            BasicNameValuePair usernameBaseNameValuePair=new BasicNameValuePair("id",u);
            BasicNameValuePair passBaseNameValuePair=new BasicNameValuePair("pass",p);
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairList.add(usernameBaseNameValuePair);
            nameValuePairList.add(passBaseNameValuePair);
            try {
                UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity=new 
                UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairList,HTTP.UTF_8);
                httppost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);
                try {
                    HttpResponse httpResponse=httpClient.execute(httppost);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                } catch (IOException e) {
                user.setText(e.getMessage());
                }

            }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException uee){
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, and provide the logcat output that includes the exception stacktrace.

Comment: You should not do this - `}catch(UnsupportedEncodingException uee){` since if you get an exception, you won't know about it and don't do anything to resolve it.
            }

Comment: Three points: 1) re formatting; StackOverflow uses 4-column tabs, so keep that in mind. You're probably better off changing tabs to spaces. b) I agree with @Simon; you should at the very least be printing an error message and maybe a stack trace in your `try` clause. And above all, iii) show us the logcat output from the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont work with network on main thread(or get `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`). use `thread class`  or `AsyncTask class`.
[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
[Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this code in android 4.0+ you get exception `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to provide any http communication.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create a separate class for getting the Request and use Asynctask to perform all your actions. Use a String to pass the URI and then pass the URI in the Asynctask. This method won't block your Main UI Thread.
Refer to this link for how to use Asynctask.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

For network operation you should use different thread rather than using main thread because using network on main thread will cause to application UI unresponsive to avoid this you should [AyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
For Example of AsyncTask use this [Link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use a different thread for sending a request. Or, the best way is to use volley requests with post method. It is faster and more efficient.